# Remove this " $ , . " of a string in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I need remove this " $ ,  . " of string with robot framework and after convert to number.

For example this string "$7,999.00"

My code:

```
${price}=    Get Text    xpath="...."
${proice}    Replace String    ,    .    $
log to console    ${price}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can be done with the `Remove String` keyword from the [String](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Remove%20String) library. It supports a variable number of arguments, so yes, you can pass all characters you need to be removed.

Do not remove the dot (`.`) though - if you do that, you'll essentially multiple the value by 100:

```
${price}=    Remove String        ${price}   ,    $
${price}=    Convert To Number    ${price}
# just to check is it really a number now - if the source string value was 10000.00:
${result}=   Evaluate    ${price} * 2
# , this should print 20000.00:
Log To Console    ${result}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for help me!

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3446126/todor-minakov
 what If I need to replace "  to blank

Comment: Use it as an argument - `${my var}=    Remove string    ${my var}    "`

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    ${price}=    Get Price String As Integer    $7,999.00
    Log To Console   \n ${price}

***Keywords***
Get Price String As Integer
    [Arguments]    ${string}
    # ignore decimal values of price string
    ${price}=    Fetch From Left    ${string}    .
    # Remove $ , . from price string
    ${price}=    Remove String    ${price}    $    ,
    # Converting value to integer
    ${value}=    Convert To Integer   ${price}
    [Return]    ${value}
```

Output: 7999

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am resolve this problem of this form:

```
#Get text of xpath
${price}    Get Text   xpath="..."
#Remove , and "
${price}    Remove String    ${price}    ,    $
#conver to number
${price}    Convert To Number    ${price}
```

Any form thanks for your help!